# .NET Core 1.1.0 and Angular 2 app: Unexpected CSS token in webpack vendor.css

Tags: css, angular, typescript, webpack, .net-core

I've deployed a **.NET Core 1.1.0 + Angular 2 + Typescript + webpack** app on ASPHostPortal. Everything works fine from Chrome and Firefox but when I try to open the site from Safari I get the following exceptions on the console:

[image]

How can I solve this?